# Excel: good way to separate text to columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Sometimes we receive spreadsheets with all of the text in one column, like the image below. I just want to know if theres a quick way to separate the text, in this case – where there are 3 digits and then the company name, into two columns in order to use it for Data Merge text fields in InDesign. I went through and inserted a comma manually in order to use the Text to Columns feature. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in luck as there is a built in tool for just that. Simply highlight your data and select the "Data Ribbon" at top. Then click "Text to Columns".

You should see this dialog:

[image]

Select "Fixed width", and click Next. From there you can drag the arrow to however many characters you are wishing to split at, in your case that seems to be 3. Click next to see a preview, select the data format if you care to change (otherwise just leave as general) then click Finish

Comment: Thank you! I knew there had to be an easier way to do it. I blew right past Fixed Width.

Comment: No problem :) Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You could use Power Query to split the data. In Power Query you can specify the delimiter and you can also tick a setting to split the data only at the *first* appearance of the delimiter.

And, with Power Query, you can save the query settings and refresh the query when new data arrives.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The text to column wizard with fixed width won't work, because if you have numbers under 10, or over 100 or over 1000, the split would happen at the wrong place. (the presence or absence of commas would also cause a problem).

You need to:

1. Replace the first space with a non used character (for example "|"
   or "¬")

   =REPLACE(A1;FIND(" ";A1);1;"|")
2. Copy and paste the result as "values"
3. Use the wizard to
   split on that unused character

Screen capture of 1
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTdf3.png

Screen capture of 2
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHeoV.png

Screen capture of 3
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YogHz.gif

(Sorry, I'm not allowed to post images)

Comment: OP clearly states that the column starts with a 3-digit number.

Comment: @Bandersnatch The screen capture clearly shows 4 characters when a comma is present and 3 characters when a comma is absent. Also, if it has at least numbers up to 64, then is close to 100, and "#" is not a "digit", so if it can have 3 digits, then it can have up to #999

Comment: @Bandersnatch The screen capture shows 2 digit numbers, so his text shouldn't be taken literally.

Comment: @Bandersnatch and the list obviously starts with 1,2,3, which are not "3 digits", so "fixed width" split, will cut the text, corrupting the data.

Comment: <Sigh> OK, I'll try to be nice and explain. 1. OP stated "there are 3 digits and then the company name".  2. # represents an arbitrary digit.  3. OP "inserted a comma manually" in some rows. Presumably he will also remove them manually.  4. Notice that OP has accepted the answer, so your assertion that "the text to column wizard with fixed width won't work" is incorrect.  Welcome to OP, I hope you make amazing contributions here.  And, in the future, I hope that you read questions carefully before answering.

Comment: @Bandersnatch It doesn't says that # represents an arbitrary digit. It cannot be presumed that 2 commas were added on 1 digits, or 53 commas will be manually removed. An accepted answer doesn't mean that there was no problem. I suggested a more robust solution which will be of general use. In the future, please read carefully before writing.